# How to stop container appearing under header using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, header, overlap

I'm building a rails app right now using bootstrap for the UX. I need help figuring out how to keep the container class from appearing under the navbar. This is what the html for the page looks like:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="pull-right"> Title text goes here </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>


<div class="container">
    <%= yield %> <br / >
</div>
```

The only CSS on the page is css from bootstrap.

Comment: one is for content within the navbar, one is for the body fo the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look at bootstrap samples, maybe you need to add style for the body:

```
  body {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you need the div with the "container" class inside of the "navbar-inner" div?  I would suggest changing the class of that to "brand", ditching the span, and putting your title text inside that brand div, like so:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="brand pull-right">Title text goes here </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Bootstrap can be picky about how various classes are nested and you should follow the same structure as outlined in the documentation:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar